# AzureAdTokenCredentials dependency on ActiveDirectory 3.13.1.846

Tags: azure-functions, azure-media-services

**Summary:**
Trying to create a AzureAdTokenCredentials object results in FileNotFoundException trying to load Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory, Version=3.13.1.846. I have Version=3.19.4 installed.

**Details:**
I told myself I'd never be the guy who asks such a basic question but here we go. So I recently authored an Azure Function that will interact with Media Services. Step one was create the CloudMediaContext. Seems straight forward. I wrote the following code:

```
private CloudMediaContext CreateCloudMediaContext()
{
    var key = new AzureAdClientSymmetricKey(_amsClientId, _amsClientSecret);
    var credentials = new AzureAdTokenCredentials(_amsAadTenantDomain, key, AzureEnvironments.AzureCloudEnvironment);
    var provider = new AzureAdTokenProvider(credentials);

    return new CloudMediaContext(new Uri(_amsRestApiEndpoint), provider);
}
```

This promptly exploded when trying to create a new AzureAdTokenCredentials object with the dreaded FileNotFoundException which specified a pretty old version of the ActiveDirectory assembly that I'm already using for various other functionality in my app.

My question ultimately is, do I ***really*** need to install a version of the the assembly from nearly 2 years ago SxS with the latest version to fix this or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at other example Functions that are using the Azure Media Services APIs up here, https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-dotnet-functions-integration/tree/master/media-functions-for-logic-app 
you will see a similar pattern.  The version of the .NET SDK for Media Services is a bit old now... but the good news is we are going to be releasing preview of v3 of the Media Services API and a new SDK next week at the //BUILD conference.

The new SDK will only have the following two dependencies:

- Microsoft.Azure.Management.Media -Version 1.0.0
- Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory -Version 3.19.4

If you are willing to try out and move to the newer API, you can wait until early next week.

What scenario are you working on exactly? Encoding, Streaming, or Live?

Comment: Ah this explains it then. I thought I was doing something wrong when I was being prompted for such an old library. Honestly I'm merely trying to fetch the locator URI for a specific streaming asset however that has it's own set of problems given that I'm having to manually concat a bunch of stuff together to build it myself. I digress though. Thank you for the above insight.

Comment: I can help you... ping me at amshelp@microsoft.com